# run command line on Windows without showing DOS console window

Tags: python, python-3.x

is there anyway to run command line on Windows without showing DOS console window ?

can you use the following command line to give a little example ?

```
wget -r -np -nd http://example.com/packages/
```

the path to wget is `C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe`

Comment: The [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module may be useful to you.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe -r -np -nd http://example.com/packages/', shell=True)` is probably what you want...

Comment: I want shell=False ,then how to ?

Comment: the DOS console window still pops up? 
but I found when shell=True ,the DOS console window doesn't pop up,anyone can explain why ?